# SetState not re-rendering and galleries getting mixed

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a custom react project and I have a problem that a wrong array of images is showing when a component should be rerendered, I am not sure what the real issue is but I think I might be missing a rerendering somewhere, i will try to explain as best as i can below please seek more info if you need it, also try to bear with me there's a link at the end :)

NOTE: gallery component is where you choose the gallery and ContainerPhotography is the one where image arrays that don't work are shown

this is the JSON object that i am using in state

```
    fotografije: [
  {
    "naslov": "Sculptures",
    "id": "f00",
    "brSlika": "10 image Gallery",
    "naslovnaSlika": "http://lanapavkov.com/content/img1.png",
    "naslovKlasa": "sculptures_naslov",
    "slikeUGaleriji": ["http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp0.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp1.jpg",  "http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp2.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp3.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp4.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp5.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp6.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp7.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp8.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/skulpture/skp9.jpg"],
    "slikaKlasa": "sculptures"
  }, {
    "naslov": "Captions",
    "id": "f01",
    "brSlika": "16 image Gallery",
    "naslovnaSlika": "http://lanapavkov.com/content/una_gallery.png",
    "naslovKlasa": "captions_naslov",
    "slikeUGaleriji": ["http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt1.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt2.jpg","http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt3.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt4.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt5.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt6.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt7.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt8.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt9.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt10.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt11.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt12.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt13.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt14.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt15.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/captions/cpt16.jpg",],
    "slikaKlasa": "captions"
  }, {
    "naslov": "Eva",
    "id": "f02",
    "brSlika": "9 image Gallery",
    "naslovnaSlika": "http://lanapavkov.com/content/Eva_prez.png",
    "naslovKlasa": "eva_naslov",
    "slikeUGaleriji": ["http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/1.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/2.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/3.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/4.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/4(1).jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/5.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/6.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/7.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/8.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/10.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/11.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/12.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/13.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/14.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/15.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/16.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/17.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/18.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/19.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/20.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/21.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/22.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/23.jpg", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/eva/24.jpg"],
    "slikaKlasa": "eva"
  }, {
    "naslov": "Exposures",
    "id": "f03",
    "brSlika": "19 image Gallery",
    "naslovnaSlika": "http://lanapavkov.com/content/street_gallery_1.png",
    "naslovKlasa": "exposures_naslov",
    "slikeUGaleriji": ["http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp1.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp2.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp3.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp4.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp5.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp6.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp7.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp8.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp9.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp10.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp11.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp12.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp13.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp14.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp15.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp16.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp17.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp18.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp19.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp20.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp21.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp22.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp23.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp24.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp25.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp26.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp27.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp28.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp29.JPG", "http://lanapavkov.com/content/exposures/exp30.JPG"],
    "slikaKlasa": "exposures"
  }
]
```

in my app.js I loop through this array to get four images on the screen that are actually buttons to trigger a gallery component

```
        <div className="photography_c">
      {this.state.fotografije.map((photography, index) => {
        return  <Gallery
                    naslov={photography.naslov}
                    naslovnaSlika={photography.naslovnaSlika}
                    naslovKlasa={photography.naslovKlasa}
                    brSlika={photography.brSlika}
                    key={photography.id}
                    slikaKlasa={photography.slikaKlasa}
                    openPhotography={() => this.injectPhotography(index)} />
                  })}
    </div>
```

the actual gallery component looks like this

```
   const Gallery = (props) => {
  return (
      <div onClick={props.openPhotography} className="singleGallery">
        <div className={props.naslovKlasa}>
          <h3>{props.naslov}</h3>
          <p>{props.brSlika}</p>
          <img className="plus_icon" src="http://lanapavkov.com/content/more.png" alt="open" />
        </div>
        <img className={props.slikaKlasa} src={props.naslovnaSlika} alt="nova slika "/>
      </div>
  )
}
```

the openPhotography I use to import one of the clicked objects into an empty state and use its info to fill out another component that is the actual selected gallery. the function looks like this

```
  injectPhotography = (fotografijaIndex) => {
    let {brslikeuG} = this.state;
    brslikeuG = 1;
    this.setState({brslikeuG: brslikeuG});

    const {updownPhotography} = this.state;
    updownPhotography.push("position-top-photography");
    this.setState({updownPhotography: updownPhotography});
    const selectedPhotography = this.state.fotografije.find((fotografija, index) => index === fotografijaIndex)
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
       selectedPhotography
    }))
  }
```

*brslikeuG is a number I print out on the page so the user knows how many images there are

the actual component with the sldes and images is this component

```
  const ContainerPhotography = (props) => {
return (
      <div className={props.klasa.join(' ')}>
      <div className="arrow_holder">
        <p className="br_slike">{props.brSlike}/{props.selectedPhotography && props.selectedPhotography.slikeUGaleriji && props.selectedPhotography.slikeUGaleriji.length}</p>
        <img onClick={props.klikLevo} src="http://lanapavkov.com/content/back_arrow.png" alt="right_arrow" />
        <img onClick={props.klikDesno} src="http://lanapavkov.com/content/back_arrow.png" alt="left_arrow" />
      </div>
      <div className="horizontal_container" style={{ left: props.left }}>
      {props.selectedPhotography && props.selectedPhotography.slikeUGaleriji && props.selectedPhotography.slikeUGaleriji.map((slika, index)=> {
               return <ImageLoopPhoto Key={'Key-'+index} url={slika} />
       })}
      </div>
        <img onClick={props.zatvori} src="http://lanapavkov.com/content/close.png" alt="close" className="close-popup" />
      </div>
  )
}
```

and it is called from the app.js

```
<ContainerPhotography
  selectedPhotography={this.state.selectedPhotography}
  klasa={this.state.updownPhotography}
  zatvori={this.closePreviewPhotography}
  left={this.state.left}
  brSlike={this.state.brslikeuG}
  klikDesno={this.pomeranjeGalerijePhotoDesno}
  klikLevo={this.pomeranjeGalerijePhotoLevo}/>
```

and the last component that prints images in a loop is this one

```
const ImageLoopPhoto = (props) => {
  return (
      <div className="horizontal_element">
        <img src={props.url} alt="alt"/>
      </div>
  )
}
```

when I close the actual slide component just the css classes are changed so I won't bother you with that.

THE PROBLEM: when you click on the first image, go through the gallery, close it and open the second gallery the images from the first gallery are still there and when you try to click the arrows the images change to the second array (sometimes they don't). I am not sure if this is a rerendering issue or just a bad practice of everything. I'm just starting out with react so please have patience and all advice is welcome

also you can see this live on lanapavkov.com if you go to photography on top and click around you can see the issue.

Comment: How ContainerPhotography  component is being used  and inside which component? Can you please share  some code to demonstrate that?

Comment: @imk I have added it, it is called in app.js

Comment: try adding the prop `key={this.state.selectedPhotography.id}` to `ContainerPhotography`. That will reload the `ContainerPhotography` component when the selected photography changes. That may be what you want. If you could put this in a code sandbox or stack snippet, it would help debugging this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please replace component ContainerPhotography  with below codes. **notice that i changed the  props Key to key. lowercase k**. and use url as key.

```
    const ContainerPhotography = (props) => {
return (
      <div className={props.klasa.join(' ')}>
      <div className="arrow_holder">
        <p className="br_slike">{props.brSlike}/{props.selectedPhotography && props.selectedPhotography.slikeUGaleriji && props.selectedPhotography.slikeUGaleriji.length}</p>
        <img onClick={props.klikLevo} src="http://lanapavkov.com/content/back_arrow.png" alt="right_arrow" />
        <img onClick={props.klikDesno} src="http://lanapavkov.com/content/back_arrow.png" alt="left_arrow" />
      </div>
      <div className="horizontal_container" style={{ left: props.left }}>
      {props.selectedPhotography && props.selectedPhotography.slikeUGaleriji && props.selectedPhotography.slikeUGaleriji.map((slika, index)=> {
               return <ImageLoopPhoto key={slika} url={slika} />
       })}
      </div>
        <img onClick={props.zatvori} src="http://lanapavkov.com/content/close.png" alt="close" className="close-popup" />
      </div>
  )
}
```

let me know, if this fix your issues.
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you change the `key` prop in the component doing the iteration, instead of in the item component?

Comment: um, I don't think that's correct yet :) Your key is based solely on the index, and that means that things can get mixed up if items change order...

Comment: How is that possible? In array, 'index' is always unique. I mean index will be 0,1,2,3,....

Comment: yeah, it's unique, but it doesn't always correlate to the same item. see [Index as key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). You can sometimes get away with it, but when things are not appearing in the order you expect, or things aren't updating, then it's usually because your key is an index, not an identifier.

Comment: You are right. But in this case , using index for key is OK, i guess. As  the list is static,  it has no id and,  never be re-ordered. Thanks Motzner

Comment: thank you for the further explanation @GarrettMotzner